# How to decode a Unicode character in a string

Tags: c#

How do I decode this string  'Sch\u00f6nen' (`@"Sch\u00f6nen"`) in C#, I've tried HttpUtility but it doesn't give me the results I need, which is "Schönen".

Comment: Have you looked at the System.Text.Encoding classes? You might be able to use the [UTF-8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) encoding to decode the Unicode string content

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`Regex.Unescape` did the trick:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(@"Sch\u00f6nen");
```

<sub>Note that you need to be careful when testing your variants or writing unit tests: `"Sch\u00f6nen"` is already `"Schönen"`. You need `@` in front of string to treat `\u00f6` as part of the string.</sub>

Comment: I know this comment is old but you have fixed my issue with your comment about adding `@` before the unicode. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

If you landed on this question because you see `"Sch\u00f6nen"` (or similar `\uXXXX` values in string constant) - it is not encoding. It is a way to represent Unicode characters as escape sequence similar how string represents New Line by `\n` and Return by `\r`.

I don't think you have to decode.

```
string unicodestring = "Sch\u00f6nen";
Console.WriteLine(unicodestring);
```

Schönen was outputted.

Comment: Well it shows up as "Sch\u00f6nen" when I output it on the windows phone emulator so it needs to be escaped. The user who answered my question and then deleted his post got the correct answer, I don't know why he deleted it.

Comment: I think you two misunderstood each other :) @findcaiyzh, if you update your example with `string unicodestring = "Sch\\u00f6nen";` you'll get the case @M_K is talking about. This scenario is usual when working with JSON result, retrieved from a remote endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a code that covnerts unicode strings to actual chars. (But the best answer in this topic works fine and less complex).

```
string stringWithUnicodeSymbols = @"{""id"": 10440119, ""photo"": 10945418, ""first_name"": ""\u0415\u0432\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0439""}";
var splitted = Regex.Split(stringWithUnicodeSymbols, @"\\u([a-fA-F\d]{4})");
string outString = "";
foreach (var s in splitted)
{
    try
    {
        if (s.Length == 4)
        {
            var decoded = ((char) Convert.ToUInt16(s, 16)).ToString();
            outString += decoded;
        }
        else
        {
            outString += s;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        outString += s;
    }
}
```

Comment: With the `length==4` check, pretty sure this could give false results for something like `\uAAAAAAA\uAAAA` that has length 4 strings between unicode chars. The core conversion is decent enough to write a parser from, though.