# converting unicode to actual character C#

Tags: c#, unicode, decoding

I have a string "Some string that I am using but Poacher\u2019s shows unicode!" I'm trying to have the Unicode convert into the ' character.

Comment: I think you need to use something from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303257/how-to-decode-a-unicode-character-in-a-string

Comment: The answer Fabien provided proved to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like that should work :

```
string text = "Some string that I am using but Poacher\u2019s shows unicode!";
byte[] textBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, textBytes));
```

Please see the [Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) class on MSDN.

Comment: This was just what I was looking for thanks