# Convert Unicode character back to its original string representation

Tags: c#, string, unicode

I have a string defined `public const string Numeric0 = "\u0030";`. C# is interpreting it as a Unicode character, which is useful to part of my application, but I also want to output the string in its original `"\u0030"` format. I've tried most related answers here from SO, but haven't really made any progress. Thoughts?

Expected c# input:

```
public const string Numeric0 = "\u0030";
var str = SomeOperation(Numeric0);
```

Expected output:

```
str == @"\u0030"
```

Comment: You want the string to *literally* contain `"\u0030"`?

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried and what the result was? It's expect `$@"\u{(int) ch:x4}"` to work (for a `char ch`). Note that if you need to handle surrogate pairs (formatting as `\Uxxxxxxxx`) that would be slightly trickier.

Comment: Yes, literally "\u0030"

Comment: So... `"\\u0030"` or `@"\u0030"`? Or if you want the string to contain the unicode character 0030, but still want to print it out as `\u0030`, see @JonSkeet's comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting unicode to actual character C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611182/converting-unicode-to-actual-character-c-sharp)

Comment: I've tried various `Regex.Escape` and the one @JohnSmith linked. That is how to convert to the actual represented character, not get the escaped unicode string.

Comment: @Drise I think you need to add some expected input and output. At the moment it's not at all clear what you want, and why the other answers on here don't apply to you

Comment: @canton7 Edited.

Comment: See @JonSkeet's comment - that should do what you want.

Comment: Your "expected output" would be just for an operation that returns its input. I assume you *actually* want `@"\u0030"`. It's also not clear what you want to happen if there are multiple characters.

Comment: @JonSkeet Multiple characters are not part of a valid input. Sorry for not clarifying. Is there a cleaner way to do `var x = $@"\u{(int)Numeric0.ToCharArray()[0]:x4}";`, which is doing what I want?

Comment: `$@"\u{(int)Numeric0[0]:x4}"` -- no need for `ToCharArray()`. Also, why not declare your const as a `char`, rather than a `string`,  if it will only contain a single character?

Comment: @canton7 Derp... Also, the tool I originally used to grab all these values gave them to me as strings. Didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want a kind of `string` *dump* (when each `char` is represented in a form of unicode `\uxxxx` symbol), let's implement it with a help of *Linq*:

```cs
using System.Linq;

...

public static string Dump(string value) => value == null
  ? "null" //TODO: put desired representation of null string here
  : "\"" + string.Concat(value.Select(c => $"\\u{((int)c):x4}")) + "\"";

...

public const string Numeric0 = "\u0030";

...

string str = Dump(Numeric0);

Console.WriteLine(str);
Console.WriteLine(Dump("abc 123"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
"\u0030"
"\u0061\u0062\u0063\u0020\u0031\u0032\u0033"
```

Comment: Without `<!-- language: csharp -->` code is not highlighted for me.

Comment: @Sinatr: I'm very sorry, it seems I've spoilt your edit

Comment: It's probably a bug on my side, now code looks fine without it.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko A bit above and beyond, but yea this will do.