# C# Convert string to char - Unicode

Tags: c#, string, unicode, char, type-conversion

Look at this Code:

```
string s = "0x00A5";
Console.WriteLine(((char)s).ToString()); //Error
Console.WriteLine(((char)0x00A5).ToString());
```

I know why there is an error but i have no Idea how to solve this.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

```
string stringHex = "7A";
int intFromHex = int.Parse(stringHex , System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) + 30;
string hex = intFromHex.ToString("X");
switch(hex.Length)
{
    case 2:
        hex = "0x00" + hex;
        break;
    case 3:
        hex = "0x0" + hex;
        break;
    case 4:
        hex = "0x" + hex;
        break;
}
char c = (char)hex;
string s = "0x00A5";
Console.WriteLine(((char)s).ToString());
Console.WriteLine(((char)0x00A5).ToString());
```

This is the whole Code. Im trying to generate a string with random unicode Chars.

Comment: Well what is your desired output? Whats the problem?

Comment: look at the Encoding class in the System.Text namespace

Comment: `char c = (char)Convert.ToInt32("0x00A5", 16);` for `¥` if thats what your asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode a Unicode character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303257/how-to-decode-a-unicode-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to convert just *one* symbol, put `Convert`:

```
  string s = "0x00A5";

  // ¥
  string result = ((char)Convert.ToInt32(s, 16)).ToString();
```

If you want to convert *several* ones you have to extract them with regular expressions:

```
  string s = "0x00A50x00200x0048";

  // ¥ H
  string result = Regex.Replace(s, "0x[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}", 
    match => ((char)Convert.ToInt32(match.Value, 16)).ToString());
```

Comment: Thank u that helped

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
int val =  Convert.ToInt32("0x00A5", 16);
char c = Convert.ToChar(val);
```

or

```
char c = (char)(Convert.ToInt32("0x00A5", 16));
```