# Convert non-escaped unicode string to unicode

Tags: c#, unicode

I have a text string from a mysql database which is

```
var str = "u0393u03a5u039du0391u0399u039au0391".
```

I want to replace the unicode characters to show them as they actually appear "ΓΥΝΑΙΚΑ". If I manually escape the u with \u in .net, the conversion is done automatically.

I found the following function:

```
byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);

// Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
byte[] ascibytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII, unicodeBytes);

// Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string.
char[] asciiChars = new char[Encoding.ASCII.GetCharCount(ascibytes, 0, ascibytes.Length)];

Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(ascibytes, 0, ascibytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
return new string(asciiChars);
```

but since it has to be escaped I do

```
str =str.Replace("u", @"\u")
```

but with no luck. How can I convert this?

Comment: Is there any chance that these escapeless sequences would be mixed in with regular characters? In particular, `u`? That'd make this quite a bit more difficult.

Comment: no there is not

Comment: why is there ASCII in your code? the capital greek letters are not part of ASCII. the second attempt does not work because the backslash syntax won't  be interpreted when it is already part of a C# string literal stored in memory. the [regex library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9303257/1132334) has a function to accomplish this,.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode a Unicode character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303257/how-to-decode-a-unicode-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are essentially UTF-16 code points, so this would do (this approach is not very efficient, but I assume optimization isn't the main goal):

```
Regex.Replace(
    "u0393u03a5u039du0391u0399u039au0391",
    "u[0-9a-f]{4}",
    m => "" + (char) int.Parse(m.Value.Substring(1), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
)
```

This can't deal with the ambiguity of un-escaped "regular" characters in the string: `dufface` would effectively get turned into `d` + `\uffac` + `e`, which is probably not right. It will correctly handle surrogates, though (`ud83dudc96` is ).

Using the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9303629/4137916) is another option:

```
Regex.Unescape(@"u0393u03a5u039du0391u0399u039au0391".Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("u", @"\u"))
```

The extra `\` escaping is there just in case the string should contain any backslashes already, which could be wrongly interpreted as escape sequences.

Comment: thanks, that worked! and yes optimization is not needed here Q)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
var str = "u0393u03a5u039du0391u0399u039au0391";

if (str.Length > 0 && str[0] == 'u')
    str = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 1);

string chars = string.Concat(str.Split('u').Select(s => 
    Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32("0x" + s,16))));
```