# How to get the char from a string that contains unicode escape sequence which starts with "\u"

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, decoding

I did quite a lot of researches but still could not figure it out. Here is an example, I got a string contains `"\uf022"` (a character from another language), how can I change the whole string into the char `'\uf022'`?

Update:
the string "\uf022" is retrieved during runtime (read from other sources) instead of directly putting a static character into the string.

For example:

```
string url = "https://somesite/files/abc\uf022def.pdf";
int i = url.IndexOf("\\");
string specialChar = url.substring(i, 6);
```

How do I get the char saved in the string `specialChar`?

I would like to use this char to do UTF-8 encoding and generate the accessible URL `"https://somesite/files/abc%EF%80%A2def.pdf"`.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what you mean. It would help if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you asking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303257/how-to-decode-a-unicode-character-in-a-string?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I'm new to the website, should've read this first.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you very very much, this solved my problem!!

Answer (score 1):

> how can I change the whole string into the char '\uf022'?

Strictly speaking, you can't change the characters of the string you have (because strings are immutable), but you can make a new one that meets your demands..

```
var s = new string('\uf022', oldstring.Length);
```

Your title of your question reads slightly differently.. it sounds like you want a string that is only the F022 chars, i.e. if your string has 10 chars and only 3 of them are F022, you want just the 3.. which could be done by changing `oldstring.Length` above, into `oldstring.Count(c => c == '\uf022')`

..and if you mean your string is like "hello\uf022world" and you want it to be like "helloworld" then do

```
var s = oldstring.Replace("\\uf022", "\uf022");
```

If you have the \uf022 in a string (6 chars) and you want to replace it with its actual character, you can parse it to int and convert to char when you replace..

```
var oldstring = "hello\uf022world";
var given = "\uf022";
var givenParsed = ((char)Convert.ToInt32(given.Substring(2), 16)).ToString();
var s = oldstring.Replace(given, givenParsed);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Caius. Apologies that I forgot to mention that the string "\uf022" is generated during runtime (read from other sources) instead of directly putting a static character into the string. How can I achieve that in this situation? Thank you.

Comment: @Warren Substitute `'\uf022'` with the variable that holds the character. For example: `char someCharacter = 'a'; s = new string(someCharacter, oldstring.Length);`.

Comment: So is your question then "I have a string that literally looks like hello\uf022world ie 16 characters long, and I want to transform it into helloworld ie 11 characters long, and I'm given "\uf022" in a string variable 6 characters long"