# Font Awesome code as string not rendering as expected

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a `Label` like this:

```
              new Label
                {
                    FontFamily = FontAwesome.Light,
                    FontSize = 50,
                    TextColor = Palette.Common.Accent,
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
                    VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                }
                .Bind(Label.TextProperty, nameof(MyFieldModel.iconCode))
```

`iconCode` in `MyFieldModel` is a `string`.

```
string iconCode = "f135";
```

This just renders as literal string `f135` instead of a Rocket. (f135 is code for a rocket in fontawesome).

But when I change it to:

```
string iconCode = "\uf135";
```

It renders as Rocket.

If I get icon code input as `string` like "f135". How do I convert it to `\uf135` format in code.

I tried all the following and none are working:

```
// try 1
string iconCode = "\\u" + myCodeString;
// try 2
string iconCode = @"\u" + myCodeString;
// try 3
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("U+{0:X4} ", iconCode);
```

How do I make it work ?

Comment: are you sure your binding is working?  `iconCode` should be a property, not a field.

Comment: Yes. My binding is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/9303629/199364, try

```cs
= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(@"\u" + myCodeString);
```

For example, if `myCodeString` contains `"f135"`, this is equivalent to

```cs
= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(@"\uf135");
```

which should give you the same result as:

```cs
= "\uf135";
```

a string containing that single unicode character.